# Contagem de elementos de uma matriz, armazenando informações em outra

Tags: python, matriz

Olá, sou iniciante em python e estou fazendo um exercício que se constitui em ler todos os números de uma matriz e adicionar em outra matriz os números existentes na anterior e quantas vezes eles aparecem. Por consequência, a matriz 2 vai ter duas linhas, uma contendo os numeros, e na segunda quantas vezes eles aparecem.
Por exemplo, se existe um número 10 e ele aparece 3 vezes, a segunda matriz terá na primeira linha o numero 10, e na segunda o número 3, os dois na mesma coluna.

OBS: Considere a primeira matriz como uma qualquer já declarada.

```
...

matriz2=[]
linha1 = []
linha2 = []
qntde=0
linha1.append(0)
for l in range(numerodelinhas):
    for c in range(numerodecolunas):
        qntde = 0
        if(linha1.count(matriz[l][c])==0):
            if(l==0 and c == 0):
                linha1[0]=matriz[0][0]
            if(l != 0 or c != 0):
                linha1.append(matriz[l][c])
            for n in range(numerodelinhas):
                qntde = qntde + matriz[n].count(matriz[l][c])
            linha2.append(qntde)

matriz2.append(linha1)
matriz2.append(linha2)
cm2=0
for n in matriz2[0]:
    print (matriz2[0][cm2]," - ",matriz2[1][cm2])
    cm2+=1
```

O código deu certo, mas ele não me agrada nem um pouco. Teria um jeito de deixa-lo mais enxuto?

Answer (score 1):

Dá pra tirar proveito da classe [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), que recebe um `iterable` ou `mapping` e faz a contagem de elementos.
O único ajuste é transformar a matriz em uma lista, mas isso é facilmente resolvido com o método [itertools.chain()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

Segue um exemplo de uso:

```py
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

# Matrix 4x4 apenas para exemplo
matriz = [
    [2, 4, 6, 8],
    [1, 2, 3, 5],
    [1, 1, 10, 20],
    [1, 2, 4, 7],
]

contador = Counter(chain.from_iterable(matriz))

# printa o objeto Counter, sendo as chaves o elemento
# contado e os valores quantas vezes eles aparecem na matriz
print(contador)
```

Output:

```
Counter({
    1: 4,
    2: 3,
    4: 2,
    6: 1,
    8: 1,
    3: 1,
    5: 1,
    10: 1,
    20: 1,
    7: 1
})
```

[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/ScentedPhonyCarriers)

**edit**: `chain(*matriz)` alterado para `chain.from_iterable(matriz)` para manter o carregamento da matriz *lazy*. (sugestão: @nosklo)

Comment: Neste caso não faz diferença mas normalmente é melhor usar o `chain.from_iterable`:  `Counter(chain.from_iterable(matriz))`

Comment: Verdade @nosklo, usei unpacking por praticidade, mas em um caso real talvez não seja performático. Vou editar a resposta, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tem um jeito muito mais fácil de lidar com arrays e matrizes em python, que é utilizar uma biblioteca chamada numpy. Exemplo:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

# matriz1 gerada aleatoriamente de números de 0 a 5 com tamanho 3x3
In [2]: matriz1 = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(3,3))

In [3]: matriz1
Out[3]: 
array([[1, 2, 4],
       [3, 1, 1],
       [2, 4, 4]])

# retorna os elementos únicos e o número de vezes em que cada um aparece
In [4]: elementos, contagem = np.unique(matriz1, return_counts=True)


# empilha os dois arrays de forma vertical, elementos em cima e contagem embaixo
In [5]: matriz2 = np.vstack([elementos, contagem])

In [6]: matriz2
Out[6]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [3, 2, 1, 3]])
```

Para mais informações e documentação: [http://www.numpy.org](http://www.numpy.org/). O numpy é a biblioteca base para quem trabalha com machine learning e ciência de dados. Existem vários tutoriais disponívels, vale a pena dar uma conferida.